# Ubuntu 17.10 64 bit freezes if left Idle

Tags: upgrade, freeze

I have updated my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 17.04 and then to 17.10 . After upgrading to 17.10 I found that Synaptic Package Manager failing to launch after authentication. Later on I found that it is freezing if kept Idle for about 10 minutes. I tried Wayland, Xorg and Unity after researching on internet but it still freezes whatever display server I choose. I have done a sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get full-upgrade and finally sudo autoremove as suggested on the #ubuntu channel in freenode IRC. But still face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it freezes because the display manager (GDM) defaults to Wayland (with Xorg as a fallback) and you machine might not support Wayland. My machine actually froze, too, while GDM was trying to use Wayland. I just disabled it in */etc/gdm3/custom.conf*. Just uncomment `WaylandEnable=false`.